# join() PHP function removes duplicated values?

Tags: php, function, join, duplicates

how are you doing?
When I use the join() function with duplicated values in an array, the join function returns the array but removing duplicates and I dont want that!

Example:

```
$array= array(1, 2, 2, 2);
$res = join(',', $array);
```

I get this:

```
1,2
```

but I want the result to be:

```
1,2,2,2
```

Hope someone can help me! Thank you

Comment: Works fine when I copy and paste what you have there. Any more detail you can give us?

Comment: This code does not do what you say: http://codepad.org/mjentvlR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say this is your code:

```
while ($coordenada = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $arrayX[$coordenada['ARTICULO']] = $coordenada['ARTICULO'];       
    $arrayY[$coordenada['CANTIDAD']] = $coordenada['CANTIDAD']; 
}
```

In which case, you are not populating the arrays like you think. Your code is doing this:

```
$arrayY[1] = 1;
$arrayY[2] = 2;
$arrayY[2] = 2;
$arrayY[2] = 2;
```

So only contains 2 values. If you want duplicates, change your code to this:

```
while ($coordenada = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $arrayX[] = $coordenada['ARTICULO'];          
    $arrayY[] = $coordenada['CANTIDAD']; 
}
```

Comment: yep that pretty much solved it! I dont kno WHY I was doing that!
thx and sry because the problem ended up being other thing!
Thx to nathanjosiah aswell for the help !

Answer (score 4):

use [implode](https://www.php.net/implode): `implode(',', $array)` even though join is just an alias of implode, it is the proper function to use

Comment: [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: I tried using implode() before posting this but I got the same result as the join() function

Comment: using the exact array you posted except with implode will give you the desired result. How are you creating the array? Is it possible you are overwriting values or passing it through `array_unique`?

Comment: Im creating the array like this:

while ($coordenada = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
 $arrayX[$coordenada['ARTICULO']] = $coordenada['ARTICULO'];       $arrayY[$coordenada['CANTIDAD']] = $coordenada['CANTIDAD'];
   }

arrayY is the one that has duplicated values...Are you saying im avoiding the duplicated values doing this?

Comment: its possible that `$arrayX[$coordenada['ARTICULO']]` is overwriting. if `$coordenada['ARTICULO']` had the same value more than once, it would only keep the last value of `$coordenada['ARTICULO']`

Comment: Try just echoing `$coordenada['ARTICULO']` and see if you get any duplicates

Comment: arrayX is generated correctly... the one that has the duplicated values is arrayY... for some reason is avoiding the repeated values.
I echoed $coordenada['CANTIDAD'] and I get all the values 1,2,2,2. Its weird cause is not saving the full array, only saves 1,2

Comment: what happens when you execute this `echo implode(',', array(1,2,2,2));`

Comment: I get 1,2,2,2 as expected but for some reason when I create the array inside the loop, arrayY is not saving all the values. 
Its not a problem of the join() or implode() function :P
Im going to check out what may be happening. Thx!